# "No appropriate python interpreter found. command terminated with exit code 1"

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, cqlsh

I am trying to perform replication in Cassandra. The cassandra nodes are setup in kubernetes. I am running it locally. I am just a beginner. I am unable to run cqlsh on the cassandra pods.
The configuration file for the pods is:

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: StatefulSet
    metadata:
      name: cassandra
      labels:
        app: cassandra
    spec:
      serviceName: cassandra
      replicas: 3
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: cassandra
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: cassandra
        spec:
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 1800
          containers:
          - name: cassandra
            image: gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v14
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            ports:
            - containerPort: 7000
              name: intra-node
            - containerPort: 7001
              name: tls-intra-node
            - containerPort: 7199
              name: jmx
            - containerPort: 9042
              name: cql
            resources:
              limits:
                cpu: "100m"
                memory: 1Gi
              requests:
                cpu: "100m"
                memory: 1Gi
            securityContext:
              capabilities:
                add:
                  - IPC_LOCK
            lifecycle:
              preStop:
                exec:
                  command: 
                  - /bin/sh
                  - -c
                  - nodetool drain
            env:
              - name: MAX_HEAP_SIZE
                value: 512M
              - name: HEAP_NEWSIZE
                value: 100M
              - name: CASSANDRA_SEEDS
                value: "cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local"
              - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
                value: "K8Demo"
              - name: CASSANDRA_DC
                value: "DC1-K8Demo"
              - name: CASSANDRA_RACK
                value: "Rack1-K8Demo"
              - name: POD_IP
                valueFrom:
                  fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: status.podIP
    #        readinessProbe:
    #          exec:
    #            command:
    #            - /bin/bash
    #            - -c
    #            - /ready-probe.sh
    #          initialDelaySeconds: 20
    #          timeoutSeconds: 10
            # These volume mounts are persistent. They are like inline claims,
            # but not exactly because the names need to match exactly one of
            # the stateful pod volumes.        
            volumeMounts:
            - name: cassandra-data-storage
              mountPath: "/mnt/data"
          volumes:
            - name: cassandra-data-storage
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: cassandra-claim
      # These are converted to volume claims by the controller
      # and mounted at the paths mentioned above.
      # do not use these in production until ssd GCEPersistentDisk or other ssd pd
    #  volumeClaimTemplates:
    #    - metadata:
    #        name: cassandra-claim
    #      spec:
    #        storageClassName: localstorage
    #        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
    #        resources:
    #          requests:
    #            storage: 1Gi
    #        selector:
    #           matchLabels:
    #            type: local
    
    
    ---
    kind: PersistentVolume
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: cassandra-data-volume
      labels:
        type: local
    spec:
      storageClassName: local-storage
      capacity:
        storage: 1Gi
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      hostPath:
        path: "/mnt/data"
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      name: cassandra-claim
    spec:
      storageClassName: local-storage
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Details of pods running & the error:

```sh
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/cassandra$ k get all
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
pod/nginx-sample-9456bbbf9-9v78w   1/1     Running   2 (40m ago)   18h
pod/nginx-sample-9456bbbf9-4kdq5   1/1     Running   2 (40m ago)   18h
pod/nginx-sample-9456bbbf9-4nc8d   1/1     Running   2 (40m ago)   18h
pod/cassandra-1                    1/1     Running   0             12m
pod/cassandra-2                    1/1     Running   0             12m
pod/cassandra-0                    1/1     Running   0             12m

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.152.183.1   <none>        443/TCP    25d
service/cassandra    ClusterIP   None           <none>        9042/TCP   170m

NAME                           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx-sample   3/3     3            3           18h

NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-sample-9456bbbf9   3         3         3       18h

NAME                         READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/cassandra   3/3     12m

ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/cassandra$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty cassandra-0 -- cqlsh
No appropriate python interpreter found.
command terminated with exit code 1

ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/cassandra$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty cassandra-0 -- /bin/bash
root@cassandra-0:/# cqlsh
No appropriate python interpreter found.

root@cassandra-0:/#
```

Comment: Thanks @david-makogon for the editing, could you please let me know how you did that? Thanks

Comment: I clicked the "edit" button - same as you can do, except I can edit other people's questions as necessary (such as formatting for readability, as I did here)